# Neo4j Cypher Query with regex not working

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to make a cypher query into neo4j that matches a simple regular expresion but even if the property 'domeniu' exists and the returned string contains the substring I am searching for the query: `match (n)-[r]-() where r.domeniu =~ '.*Baruri.*' return n` is not working.
I have attached a picture to exemplify my dilemma.
[image]

Comment: what version are you using

Comment: I tried it with 2.1 and it works there at least. Perhaps you can share the queries that create your data? E.g. as github gist.

Comment: The version is Neo4j 2.1.1

Comment: The data was created from a Java program and it's pretty complex is not just a copy and paste thing... I could share the source code: https://bitbucket.org/exilonX/businessgraph/src/e8699cdd44a084711a24ad2fe7f64e24e7ed3913/Graph/src/bman/graph/Neo4jIOBMan.java?at=master

Comment: @exilonX: As a hunch, this *might* be a problem with the way neo4j's regexp handling processes strings with non-ASCII characters. So, it would good if you could share at least the data string(s) that contain "Baruri".

Comment: I have outlined the string that contains Baruri in the picture.

Comment: I tried it with german special characters like äöß and swedish, spanish etc. øñ and it worked for me.

Comment: perhaps you can share an UTF-8 CSV file with those names for us to try?

Comment: I have exported the output of the query match (n)-[r]-() return distinct r.domeniu limit 100, you can download it from here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-M0-nz3PrF-MUFmM3RsUmtuWU0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I should point out that even if I put the regex: '.*563.*' I still don't get any matches even thoug a r.domeniu exists that contains 563.